# Can not boot from Live USB on Toshiba Satellite Click mini

Tags: windows-8, live-usb, toshiba-satellite

I've got a new Toshiba Satellite Click Mini and as usual, I'd like to get rid of Windows and install Lubuntu (15.04) ASAP. So I entered BIOS settings (<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and disabled secure boot. Then, when I enter boot menu (using <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) and choose USB, the system just falls back to Windows.

It is really frustrating as I can not bear Windows for any period of time and It is my [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625949/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-idealpad-flex-10) new laptop with UEFI BIOS on which I have trapped in Windows.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it could be your usb stick, I had one that would appear to work perfectly except it wouldn't boot from it. Try a different one.

Only wanted to comment but can't.

Comment: Well, I burned another USB using Unetbootin but still got the same nasty problem.

Comment: the only other problem I could think of would be trying to run 64bit on a 32 bit system but I assume this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Similar problem with My Toshiba Satellite L50-B where every time I tried booting from USB it wouldn't I searched numerous website all saying the same thing in the end I gave up and started testing BIOS settings Myself and found that if I changed the USB 3.0 setting to disable so it boots the laptop into thinking its using USB ports in 2.0 mode I instantly Am able to boot Windows setup or anything similar with no problems at all hope this may help some of You. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to disable UEFI to boot Ubuntu from USB...

I'm not sure how you created the bootable usb, but you need a properly formatted drive with the 'boot' flag enabled.

Try this:

1. Reboot, make sure the usb drive is in place.
2. Look in your documentation for the key that activates BIOS menu. Press and hold that key until BIOS menu opens.
3. When you see the various boot options, one should be UEFI USB drive, select that one.

   Also, you should probably reset the BIOS to default settings.

   If that doesn't work, try using UNETBOOTIN to make the USB bootable drive.

   Remember, there are resources here for you to use. Also, review the info that came with your computer.

   Good luck!

Comment: Actually I used UNETBOOTIN to make the Live USB, as I always do. Then I tried both Ubuntu and Lubuntu 15.05 (32 bit) on 2 different USB sticks.

Comment: Did you format the USB disk before you created your bootable USB? Before you create, format the drive to FAT32... also, make sure the 'boot' flag is activated.

Comment: I formated the USB as FAT32 but it did not help either.

Comment: Try this one: "Creating an Ubuntu Live USB from CD"  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/creating-an-ubuntu-live-usb-from-cd/

Answer (score 0):

From my own tests with toshiba click mini, you'll be able to boot vfat usb key with a well formated efi boot directory and file (/efi in your USB key). Bios even in 5.10 release does not support legacy boot.

Windows 8.1 32 bits usb key build from Windows 8.1 is able to boot on click mini (ntfs filesystem) while 64 bits release of Windows 8.1 usb key build from Windows 8.1 64 bits does not boot on click mini. I suspect, as discuss on toshiba eu forum, toshiba click mini bios to boot using 32 bits efi boot sheme on efi/boot/bootia32.efi.

Try boot with a gparted usb key : get the files from efi/boot (include a grub.cfg file) and use this on new USB key you create, you'll be successfull to boot linux modifying grub.cfg. Try the Manjaro (ArchLinux) distribution, this distribution as the best hardware support at that time.

Answer (score 0):

It has a 32 bit EUFI.

See this thread: https://forum.toshiba.eu/showthread.php?82516-Linux-on-Satellite-Click-Mini-L9W-any-experience

Fedlet works out of the box (although super unstable because the window manager is to heavy). What I did was install xubuntu while stealing someone else's efi encryption stuff. Then I just did some grub hacking and it worked (I think I ended up comparing what fedlet was doing vs the default xubuntu disk). Once I booted I installed xubuntu and then I had to do the same procedure for the installed OS.

Answer (score 0):

Change Boot Mode in the BIOS settings, from UEFI to CSM. 
If the option is greyed out, head to the security tab and disable security check at boot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything add infinitum and eventualy took the back off machine unplugged cmos battery plugged back in, put computer back together and hey presto no problem.there are loads of instructibles on youtube for the process ,not particularly easy.